# JSON feed in UITableView error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to get a JSON feed from Instagram to show data in my UITableView. However I get the following error and I can't figure out what the problem is:

> 2013-08-18 10:20:37.361 ttoauth[38213:c07] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75d7480
>   2013-08-18 10:20:37.362 ttoauth[38213:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75d7480'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x13c8012 0x11ede7e 0x14534bd 0x13b7bbc 0x13b794e 0x3f68 0x1ec8fb 0x1ec9cf 0x1d51bb 0x1e5b4b 0x1822dd 0x12016b0 0x26abfc0 0x26a033c 0x26a0150 0x261e0bc 0x261f227 0x261f8e2 0x1390afe 0x1390a3d 0x136e7c2 0x136df44 0x136de1b 0x22c57e3 0x22c5668 0x131ffc 0x2a4d 0x2975)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Here is my code:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [jsonResults count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}


NSDictionary *instafeed_tableview = [jsonResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *username_label = [[instafeed_tableview objectForKey:@"from"] valueForKey:@"username"];

cell.username.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", username_label];
cell.username.clipsToBounds = YES;
cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = NO;

return cell;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView :(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath :(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 191;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75d7480
```

This line tells you that you are using `objectAtIndex` (`NSArray` method) to `NSDictionary`. The error couse becouse what you receive is `NSDictionary` and you want to use it like `NSArray`.

Probably your error couse line is:

```
NSDictionary *instafeed_tableview = [jsonResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Try to debug it. I think your `jsonResults` is `NSDictionary` not `NSArray`.

Add breakpoint to this line and in output type: `po [jsonResults class];`.

**EDIT based on comment**

You got this wrong. This not you who setting what data type do you want from JSON. JSON structure determines that. For example:

```
[
   { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
   { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
   { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
```

This example retturns `NSArray` contains `NSDictionaries` in it.

```
{ 
  "name":"John" ,
  "surname":"Doe"
},
```

This will return single `NSDictionary`

This `[]` and this `{}` brackets determines what object are you dealing with.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the problem because in my header file, I set jsonResults to be a NSMutableArray.

Comment: You got this wrong. This not you who setting what data type do you want from JSON. JSON structure determines that. See my update above